# How to switch to "Use Git from command prompt?"

Tags: git, unix, command-prompt

When I first installed Git on my windows machine, I selected all the default options, one of them being:

Use Git from windows command prompt.

Now from all the Git tutorials I've seen that they suggest using

Use Git with optional Unix tools in windows command prompt.

Is there a way to update the install with that setting or should I uninstall and reinstall Git with Unix tools enabled?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to use Git on the default Windows CMD, I'd just update your PATH environment variable. It's literally all that does (In my case at least). Find the git executable and append it to the end of your PATH.

If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me, I haven't used Windows in a few months (Thanks Arch Linux).

Another thing I should mention: Should your question be on a different website? This is a programmer questions website.

Comment: Thanks! How do I add to path environment variables?

Comment: You visit Advanced settings under System, and click Environment Variables (I forget which tab it's in) and append the git executable path to the end of path.